# view not in the window hierarchy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I have created a function in app delegate which i run from a view but when I comeback to run the function again it gives me

```
<ResultViewController: 0x757dfc0> on <ViewController: 0x71325c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

**Error**

the app delegate code is opening a viewcontroller

code is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ViewController *view1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:view1];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
-(void)specify
{

    ResultViewController *res = [[ResultViewController alloc]init];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:res animated:NO];

}
```

Comment: try changing name of class pls

Comment: While creating the class make UIViewController its parent class

Comment: what is the super class of ViewController class????

Answer (score 0):

Not running your code I am guessing it is because the window you are trying to add to does not exist on the view hierarchic, you are just creating views and adding them to the screen - you need to grab the actual screen itself.

Try something like
UIViewController *presentController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

ViewController *view1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[presentController presentViewController:view1 animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

While creating the class make `UIViewController` its parent class.

It seems `UIViewController` is not the parent class of your class there is no .view of your object

Comment: thanks guyz ... but i am really new could you explain a bit ... when i am calling the function specify() from viewcontroller it runs fine but when i go to another screen and comeback to viewcontroller and run the specify() again it shows the error ...

Answer (score 0):

You should present modal view controller in navigationController of rootViewController.

```
[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController presentModalViewController:res animated:NO];
```

So, if you really want to present modal view controller into rootViewController, remember:

> If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new ones are installed.

Your first attempt to show modal viewController replace view hierarchy but  self.window.rootViewController did not change and it is not in the window hierarchy anymore.

Or something like that.